# Wifi doesn't connect if I'm upstairs

Tags: 10.10, wireless

I'm finding that Wifi connects when I'm in the living room, where the internet router etc is. But if I try to connect upstairs it is a no go. Booting in Windows 7 (dual boot :D ) I find that Wifi connects. I find this very confusing and have it since the install. Please help!

Kind regards.

```
#sudo lshw -c network
*-network               
       description: Wireless interface
       product: PRO/Wireless 5100 AGN [Shiloh] Network Connection
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:02:00.0
       logical name: wlan0
       version: 00
       serial: 00:21:5d:1a:63:58
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: pm msi pciexpress bus_master cap_list ethernet physical wireless
       configuration: broadcast=yes driver=iwlagn driverversion=2.6.35-26-generic firmware=8.24.2.12 ip=10.0.0.4 latency=0 link=yes multicast=yes wireless=IEEE 802.11abg
       resources: irq:49 memory:de200000-de201fff
```

Hope it helps!

Hello guys, just tried to connect internet upstairs and to my surprise it does connect. Don't know exactly why. Only thing I've done recently is input the codes said bij Oli and Installed Jupiter and laptop-mode-tools. I really don't know if this can effect my internet but it's the only thing I can think of.
Thanks for all the help, really appreciate it :)

PS If someone thinks it might be helpful for others I would like to help find a 'real' solution to this problem. Just post down what I need to post here and I will try my best to help.

```
/sbin/iwlist wlan0 scan wlan0     Scan completed :
      Cell 01 - Address: C0:3F:0E:50:4E:B8
                Channel:1
                Frequency:2.412 GHz (Channel 1)
                Quality=65/70  Signal level=-45 dBm  
                Encryption key:on
                ESSID:"Ziggo927471"
                Bit Rates:1 Mb/s; 2 Mb/s; 5.5 Mb/s; 11 Mb/s; 18 Mb/s
                          24 Mb/s; 36 Mb/s; 54 Mb/s
                Bit Rates:6 Mb/s; 9 Mb/s; 12 Mb/s; 48 Mb/s
                Mode:Master
                Extra:tsf=0000011fd34ba82b
                Extra: Last beacon: 83630ms ago
                IE: Unknown: 000B5A6967676F393237343731
                IE: Unknown: 010882840B162430486C
                IE: Unknown: 030101
                IE: Unknown: 2A0100
                IE: Unknown: 2F0100
                IE: IEEE 802.11i/WPA2 Version 1
                    Group Cipher : TKIP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                IE: Unknown: 32040C121860
                IE: Unknown: 2D1A7E181BFFFF000001000000000000000000000000000000000000
                IE: Unknown: 3D1601051300000000000000000000000000000000000000
                IE: Unknown: DD7C0050F204104A00011010440001021041000100103B00010310470010A2B0FCE4210B6411BC4C06A6F7EC31D21021000D4E4554474541522C20496E632E10230009574E5233353030763210240009574E523335303076321042000230311054000800060050F204000110110009574E52333530307632100800020084
                IE: Unknown: DD090010180201F0050000
                IE: WPA Version 1
                    Group Cipher : TKIP
                    Pairwise Ciphers (2) : CCMP TKIP
                    Authentication Suites (1) : PSK
                IE: Unknown: DD180050F2020101800003A4000027A4000042435E0062322F00
                IE: Unknown: DD1E00904C337E181BFFFF000001000000000000000000000000000000000000
                IE: Unknown: DD1A00904C3401051300000000000000000000000000000000000000
```

Using grep "Cell doesn't bring up anything

```
Protocol:"; /sbin/iwconfig wlan0 Protocol:: Bestand of map bestaat niet wlan0     IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:"Ziggo927471"  
      Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.412 GHz  Access Point: C0:3F:0E:50:4E:B8   
      Bit Rate=54 Mb/s   Tx-Power=15 dBm   
      Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
      Power Management:off
      Link Quality=67/70  Signal level=-43 dBm  
      Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
      Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0
```

grep "Sensitivity" -B2 Also doesn't bring anything up

Found one curious thing: It does connect upstairs but only close to my door. Everywhere else in my room is a no go, while windows does connect.

Comment: Do you notice a difference in signal-level between down-/up-stairs? What kind of device are you using? (usb/pci). Describe your system/configuration.

Comment: Could you add the model name and post the output of `/sbin/iwconfig` and `/sbin/iwpriv`

Comment: Hi, yeah When I'm upstairs the signal is slightly worse on windows that is. One thing I've found is that when I connect downstairs with wifi on ubuntu I'll still have it upstairs. When i reboot or log off and then log in again I'll have no signal though. I'm guessing that I have a pci-e (or wasn't that what you asked? )

Comment: output for iwconfig is: lo        no wireless extensions.

eth0      no wireless extensions.

wlan0     IEEE 802.11abg  ESSID:"Ziggo927471"  
          Mode:Managed  Frequency:2.462 GHz  Access Point: C0:3F:0E:50:4E:B8   
          Bit Rate=54 Mb/s   Tx-Power=15 dBm   
          Retry  long limit:7   RTS thr:off   Fragment thr:off
          Power Management:on
          Link Quality=67/70  Signal level=-43 dBm  
          Rx invalid nwid:0  Rx invalid crypt:0  Rx invalid frag:0
          Tx excessive retries:0  Invalid misc:0   Missed beacon:0

Comment: Output for iwpriv is: lo        no private ioctls.

eth0      no private ioctls.

wlan0     no private ioctls                          Have to say,right now I'm downstairs so I have internet. Don't know if this chagnes things

Comment: OW about device, a Hp Pavilion dv5 runnung ubuntu 10.10

Comment: can you connect throw a wire to the router? I have a similar problem when I'm using Spotify. What kind of router do you have? Have you the latest software? what kind of wifi card do you have? there might be a driver issue.

what I'm trying to say is that we need more information about your router and your computer.

Comment: Hi, yeah connecting trough a wire gives me a signal. My router is : Netgear; rangemax wireless n gigabit router wnr3500 v2. As far as I know I do have the latest software. About my wifi card, don't know how to check that :(

Comment: either you google your computer

Comment: alright did google it and this is what i found:Wifi-standaard 802.11g, 802.11b, 802.11n and: RJ11 Modem. Hope this helps! PS might seem as a completly noob, that's because I am :S

Comment: @user11233 Sorry for all the questions but could you edit your question to include the output of `lspci | grep net` and `sudo lshw -c network`. Again, please **edit the question** for this so the formatting is preserved. This should finally allow us to know what wireless card you have in your machine (The HP DV5 range has used several over the years).

Comment: I suspect that you are not using 802.11n or to much beacon loss. What are the outputs of: `/sbin/iwlist wlan0 scan | grep "Cell \|Protocol:"; /sbin/iwconfig wlan0 | grep "Sensitivity" -B2`

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can generally see more of your neighbor's routers from upstairs.  You might need to select a more disused channel.

Comment: While this might help the issue, it doesn't explain why Windows gets better signal. Also could you please update your post to show *how* you change a network's channel? Bonus marks if you can show them how to find a less used channel.